# Global Pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, global

I know a pointer is usually assigned upon its declaration, but I wondering if there's any way to create a global pointer in C. For example my code below: is it a good practice?

```
static int *number_args = NULL;

void pro_init(int number)
{
    number_args = &number;   /* initialize the pointer value -- is this okay? */

}
```

Comment: even if you don't assign anything, it is going to be assigned to zero by default

Comment: Not a good practise. number is basically on stack. If you are assigning global pointer to stack address, it becomes invalid when the function exits..!!

Comment: You've asked two totally different questions. Is there any way? Yes, of course ... declare the pointer at file scope, as you did. (For a *global*, omit `static`.) Is it good practice? Globals should be avoided when possible. But beyond that your *specific* usage is bogus, as Manty said. **What are you trying to do?** It's impossible to tell because you haven't shown or said how you plan to use `number_args`.

Answer (score 8):

1. Avoid globals - They are a bad idea and usually lead into problems.
2. You are taking an address of a variable on the stack. That will get reused somewhere down the line and hence having unintended results.

If you feel the need (why?) to have a global pointer then initialise if off the heap.

Comment: Downvoted for saying to avoid globals entirely. Globals have their uses, just like anything else.

Comment: @immibis The word "entirely" doesn't appear. Upvoted to counter bad downvote.

Comment: good maxim - avoid globals unless you know exactly why you need them

Answer (score 4):

That is valid. There are many good reasons to have global variables, especially static global variables. But if something doesn't need to be global, it's better to not make it global.

Also keep in mind that if more than one thread accesses that variable, you'll need to protect it somehow, probably with a mutex, or you may have race conditions.

Also, keep in mind that "number" is a stack variable. Arguments to functions and local variables are both allocated on the stack, and cease to exist outside of their scope. So unless "pro_init()" either never returns, or sets the variable back to NULL before it returns, you'll end up with an invalid pointer.

You might use heap memory instead, for example:

```
number_args = malloc(sizeof(int));
if (number_args == NULL) { /* handle malloc error */ }
*number_args = number;
```

Comment: Make the code easier.
However, some people prefer to double the size of the code but wouldn't make the "sin" of global variables.

Comment: @someuser - How does it double the size of the code just passing an extra parameter around?

Comment: You can use a lot of variables. Some of them may extend from the upper levels of the program.
The result might make your code more complicated than it could be.
I do not say "global variables is good," it's just a reasonable choice in some cases. By analogy with goto.

Comment: Good reasons to use a particular global variable are: 1) when improves performance, 2) when it makes the code simpler, 3) doing so follows an existing coding convention in an already established project, 4) when it's required to properly use some external library or API.

Comment: Any global can be encapsulated as a static variable inside a function.

Comment: @tim - What happens in the past or done by others does not make it good or right (points 3/4). It will have negligible effect on performance passing a parameter around. How does it make code simpler when the global variable is defined somewhere

Comment: @JimBalter Using a static local with a function that is basically it's get and set method sounds like a bad idea to me. You wouldn't be able to get at the value without also setting it, or else setting it would be impossible, or else you'd have to pass in a special "don't really set this" value. I'd much rather see a static global and separate functions (which might not be static) to get and set the value.

Comment: @EdHeal Following an existing coding convention when working on someone else's project is good and right. Having a global variable can be simpler than having an extra parameter to many functions, especially if those functions don't use the variable, but just pass it on. Of course it can also make the code harder to reason about. It depends on the exact situation. But if you're trying to say that global variables are always wrong, then you are wrong. Only Sith speak in absolutes.